# Mockito mock not working as expected Mockito-3.12.4

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write JUnit test for the following method of class `MessageFacade.java`

```
public void delete(FooId scopeId, DataId id)
        throws FooIllegalArgumentException,
        ConfigurationException,
        ClientException {
    ArgumentValidator.notNull(scopeId, SCOPE_ID);
    ArgumentValidator.notNull(id, "id");

    System.out.println("Query Param SCOPE_ID="+scopeId.getId().toString());
    System.out.println("Query Param ID="+id.toString());

    if (!isDatastoreServiceEnabled(scopeId)) {
        LOG.debug("Storage not enabled for account {}, return", scopeId);
        return;
    }

    //ORIGINAL CODE
   DatastoreMessage messageToBeDeleted = find(scopeId, id, DataFetchStyle.FIELDS);
   if (messageToBeDeleted != null) {
       Metadata schemaMetadata = null;
       try {
           schemaMetadata = mediator.getMetadata(scopeId, messageToBeDeleted.getTimestamp().getTime());
       } catch (FooException e) {
           LOG.warn("Retrieving metadata error", e);
       }
       String indexName = schemaMetadata.getDataIndexName();
       TypeDescriptor typeDescriptor = new TypeDescriptor(indexName, MessageSchema.MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME);
       ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient = getElasticsearchClient();
       elasticsearchClient.delete(typeDescriptor, id.toString());
   } else {
       LOG.warn("Cannot find the message to be deleted. scopeId: '{}' - id: '{}'", scopeId, id);
   }
}
```

I have written the following JUnit Test for the above method

```
@Test
public void testBulkDelete() throws ClientException, ConfigurationException, FooIllegalArgumentException {
    MessageFacade messageFacade = new MessageFacade(Mockito.mock(ConfigurationProvider.class),Mockito.mock(MessageStoreMediator.class));
    MessageFacade spyMessageFacade = Mockito.spy(messageFacade);

    DatastoreMessage datastoreMessage = new DatastoreMessageImpl();
    datastoreMessage.setTimestamp(new Date());
    Mockito.doReturn(datastoreMessage).when(spyMessageFacade).find(Mockito.any(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.any());

    Metadata schemaMetadata = Mockito.mock(Metadata.class);
    Mockito.doReturn("indexName").when(schemaMetadata).getDataIndexName();

    ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient = Mockito.mock(ElasticsearchClient.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(elasticsearchClient).delete(Mockito.any(TypeDescriptor.class), Mockito.any(String.class));

    Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spyMessageFacade).isDatastoreServiceEnabled(Mockito.any());

    FooId scopeId = new ScopeId("10");
    DataId id = new DataIdImpl("c17db8ea-93ee-48b5-9b5d-8d278180d2d9");
    spyMessageFacade.delete(scopeId, id);
}
```

I am using the version **JUnit 4.12** and **Mockito 3.12.4**

The problem is the following line (Line #242) is not being mocked
`schemaMetadata.getDataIndexName();`

and throwing **NullPointerException** as shown in the trace below

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Query Param SCOPE_ID=-41
Query Param ID=c17db8ea-93ee-48b5-9b5d-8d278180d2d9

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mars.foo.service.datastore.internal.MessageFacade.delete(MessageFacade.java:242)
    at org.mars.foo.service.datastore.internal.MessageFacadeTest.testBulkDelete(MessageFacadeTest.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
```

Also I **Need some suggestions regarding how to mock the line** `elasticsearchClient.delete(typeDescriptor, id.toString());`

Comment: Which line is line 242 of MessageFacade.java?  Is it `String indexName = schemaMetadata.getDataIndexName();`?  And is `mediator` the mocked `MessageStoreMediator` that you pass in?  If that's the case, you should keep a reference to the mocked `MessageStoreMediator` so that you can stub `getMetadata` to return your mocked `SchemaMetadata`.

Comment: Yes. Line #242 is ```String indexName = schemaMetadata.getDataIndexName()``` I haven't mocked the ```mediator```.

Comment: Where and how is the `mediator` field assigned?

Comment: It has a global reference `MessageMediator mediator;` and is assigned inside `MessageFacade` class constructor by the constructor parameter

Answer (score 0):

you're facing this problem because `Metadata schemaMetadata` is a local variable and it´s being replaced.

You can mock the `mediator.getMetadata` call to return the mock with a created Metadata object.
I have a lot of cases like this and normally I use it.

Mock this:

```
mediator.getMetadata(scopeId, messageToBeDeleted.getTimestamp().getTime());
```

this way:

```
when(mediator.getMetadata(any(), any()).thenReturn(new Metadata(){{
   setDataIndexName("IndexName"):
}};);
```

obviously, you need to mock the `mediator` before using when.

It works for me, I hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried the following but still getting `NullPointerException`. Seems like mocking is not working for `mediator`. 
`MessageMediator mediator = mock(MessageMediator.class);`
`Metadata metadata = new Metadata("index","channel","client","metric");`
`when(mediator.getMetadata(any(FooId.class),anyLong())).thenReturn(metadata);`

FYI the `MessageMediator` is an interface. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: This is the correct thing to do, but when you create your `MessageFacade`, you need to pass the mocked `MessageMediator` as the second argument, as I said in one of my comments under the question.  So instead of `messageFacade = new MessageFacade(Mockito.mock(ConfigurationProvider.class),Mockito.mock(MessageStoreMediator.class));` you need `messageFacade = new MessageFacade(Mockito.mock(ConfigurationProvider.class), mediator);`